# PSQLException: ERROR: relation does not exist for saving to jsonb column

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb, spring-jdbc

I have a `postgresql` table with `JSOB` columns and java `spring jdbc` application.

But when I try to save an entity I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO "complex" ("complex_id", "name") VALUES (?, ?)]; 
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "complex" does not exist
```

It looks like `jdbc` thinks `complex` is a separate table, but really this value should just be written to a `jsob` column.

My `postgresql` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE development
(
    id         TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    complex    JSONB,
    developer  JSONB,
    comment    TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)
```

My entity:

```java
@Table(name = "development")
public class Development {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Complex complex;

    private Developer developer;

    private String comment;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant createdAt;
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface DevelopmentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Development, String> {
}
```

Class where I try to save entity:

```
@Component
public class JdbcDevelopmentAdapter implements CreateDevelopmentPort {

    private final DevelopmentRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Development create(Development development) {
        return save(development);
    }

    private Development save(Development development) {
        return repository.save(development);
    }
}
```

Classes whose entities I am trying to store in a `jsonb` columns:

```
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Apartment {
    private String apartmentId;
    private String name;
}

@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class Developer {
    private String developerId;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: How did you implement the Complex class used as the type in Development? It looks like it is attempting to cascade the insert because it thinks Complex is an entity that should be referenced from Development, not a Jsonb-column. This will probably also be the case for Developer and Documents if they are implemented similarly.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I supplemented the description with the code of the classes that I'm trying to save in `jsonb`. I don't need `apartment` and `developer` in separate tables. It is important that this data is stored in `jsonb` columns

Comment: Where is your complex entity?

Comment: @Entity in Development class missing?

Comment: But if I add `@Entity`, then it will be a separate table. And I want to store this object in `jsonb`.

Comment: ??? Development is a database table. You need an @Entity in the Development class to make it work with Hibernate and JPARepository.